# How to add images depending on the value in an array

Tags: jquery

I have a `<li>` and images sitting next to the 'li' text. I want to insert images depending on the value that array has. Ex:

```
  $.each(state.qaccess, function (i, products) {
    var prodIcon = '';
    if (products["product"] === 'wm.od.prod.nsr'){
    prodIcon = '<span class="product-icons" id="product-icons"></span>'
    }else if (products["product"] === 'gp.od.dev.nsr'){
    prodIcon = '<span class="product-icon" id="product-icon"></span>'
    }
    allproducts.push(products.product);
});
```

where state.qaccess` is an object (shown in the img)

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the object has a field 'product' and 'product' has multiple values. Now depending on those values I'd like to insert icons. viz: for `product ==='wm.od.prod.nsr'` I'd like to insert the `<span class="product-icons"></span>` (since im using the image sprites im using the  element to insert icons).
With the above code, i get all the icons for `gp.od.dev.nsr` and none for the `wm.od.prod.nsr`? 
Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: I can't explain why you're getting `gp.od.dev.nsr` but not `wm.od.prod.nsr`. But as an aside, when you wrote `allproducts.push(products.product);` you probably meant `allproducts.push(prodIcon);`.

Comment: yes, i realized i had that mistake, i corrected and its working fine now..Thanks, anyways though!!